# Can I import data from FTP server directly to my local MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ftp

I wonder if I can import a file (like a csv file or a file in other formats) from a FTP server directly into the local MySQL using MySQL workbench?

Also, can I export the dataset directly to FTP server using MySQL workbench?

Thank you!

Comment: So you are asking if MySqlWorkbench can directly read from or directly write to an FTP server?

Comment: Thank you, ryantxr! I think I want to know both.